# Connect jhipster gateway without to uaa

Tags: jhipster, gateway

I have jhipster app using juste gate and microservice. Now I'm on another project using gateway, uaa and microservice and I want to use the uaa with my other gateway. But I don't exactly the config to change in the gateway to do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not re-generating your gateway with uaa? Run a diff and you'll know what has changed.

Comment: I was to do it quickly, so I generate another gateway and copy into it my existing code and everything is OK. But I'll try what you proposed to be ready in case I face the same situation. Thanks